# Mapping a simple region using an exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following region in the complex plane bounded by the two lines:
$$ x = y \quad\text{and}\quad x = 2y$$
It is plotted as follows: 
[Region Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZd9Z.png).
I am required to map the region under the function $$ w= f(z) = e^z $$

Unfortunately, I am unsure how to do this and how to apply eurler's formula.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$\omega=f\left ( z \right )=e^z=e^xe^{iy}=Re^{i \theta}$$
Now you only need to see what the ranges for $x$ and $y$ are and use that to find the ranges of R and $\theta$